# Why do we get the following equation in case of a One Time Pad?

Tags: one-time-pad

If m: message, M: message space, k: key, K: keyspace, c: cipher, C: cipher space and $E_k$: encryption function, such that
$E_k(m) = c,\ m,m^* \in M,\ k\in K,\ c\in C.$

My first question is, is the following equation correct for One Time Pad encryption?

$$P[E_k(m) = c] = \frac{ \sum_{m_ i\in M} \sum_{k_ i\in K} P[E_ {k_ i}(m_ i) = c] } {|M|.|K|} $$

And, my second question is, why do we get that?

Comment: What is the meaning of index $i$ in this formula? It looks out of place. If you say $\sum_{m \in M}$, your $m$ already iterates over all messages. Especially since you don't define $i$ to be anything and it appears more than once, it leads to some possible confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my interpretation of what is happening here, though it's hard to be sure without more context.  A $c \in C$ has been chosen, and we are asking "What is the probability $E_k(m)=c$ is true if $m \in M$ and $k \in K$ are chosen uniformly at random?"

To find this probability, you divide the total number of outcomes of your choices, which is $|M||K|$, by the total number of outcomes in which $E_k(m)=c$ is true.

If you interpret $P(E_{k^*}(m^*)=c)$ as 1 if $E_{k^*}(m^*)=c$ and 0 otherwise (which seems the only sensible meaning), the total number of outcomes in which $E_k(m)=c$ is $\sum_{k^*, m^*} P(E_{k^*}(m^*)=c)$.  This give the formula that you state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure if the equation is correct, as I think $P[E_{k_i}(m_i)=c_i]=1$, as the encryption always produces a cipher text (which is what you formulated I think, as there's no definition of $c_i$).

If you change the $c_i$ to $c$ however you'd calculate the average probability that any message-key-pair encrypts to $c$.

I didn't take part in such a course yet, but this looks right as for the OTP the probability that a certain message encrypts to a certain ciphertext under a certain key is basically the same as the probability that any message using any key encrypts to this specific ciphertext. So this would mean that you can't derive any relations between ciphertext and plaintext because any plaintext-key pair could match your ciphertext. This sounds pretty much like perfect secrecy and hence like an OTP.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side of your equation is just the average probability that a random message encrypted with a random key gives the ciphertext $c$.

(Exercise: Why? Hint: ${\rm avg}(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n) = (x_1 + x_2 + \dotsb + x_n) / n$.)

However, if $k$, $m$ and $c$ are all fixed (and you haven't indicated that they aren't), then $P[E_k(m)=c]$ is trivially either $0$ or $1$; either way, the equation is false.

Now, if $k$ and $m$ were uniformly distributed random variables, then the equation would be true by definition.  (If that's not obvious to you, you may want to take a quick refresher on probability theory.)

In fact, for OTP encryption, it's also possible to prove that the equation holds whenever just $k$ alone is uniformly distributed, regardless of $m$.  However, this is a non-trivial result, and does not hold for arbitrary encryption schemes.  (Hint for proving this: calculate $P[E_k(m)=c]$ for uniformly distributed $k$ and fixed $m$ and $c$, and observe that the result does not depend on the choice of $m$ (or $c$).)